# React Js: Need Temporary Buffer for Image which comes from API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, buffer, konvajs

Creating MEME's creator for portfolio showcase you can see link
http://meme-creator.myartsonline.com/

Project is not ready yet,

I'm Fetching Images from https://api.imgflip.com
which work great!

I am taking One image at a time storing in State and passing one by one Image URL (given by API) to Canvas for drawing Canvas i'm using react-konva JS

Issue-->
Image can not be on drawn on canvas if we provide by link like this
https://i.imgflip.com/2z3mn8.jpg

If image is provided from local Machine then only it is working.

Try to Download Image (GREY DOWNLOAD BUTTON) then image is Corrupted.
on my site !

What I'm Expecting :

Can I use some kind of React Buffer so i can store image into that and provide to canvas and download smoothly.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Image access from a network store such as you describe will always be an async operation for which you will have to code some kind of callback-on-completion, and do not hand the image to the canvas until this completion callback runs. See the Konva tutorials page for sample code in plain JS. Not sure how you would do this with React but assume there is ample capability there. Using local images 'feels' like it is not async but actually it is -  it just runs v quickly.

Comment: Thank you for your response , I solved it by setting image propery origin =anonymous

Comment: ok, so that would appear to be a CORS issue then?

Comment: Yes right CORS issue.

Comment: For future readers, this may assist in finding the issue. It is about enabling CORS error logging in dev react mode: https://reactjs.org/docs/cross-origin-errors.html